# Grouping, Summarizing values in R

Tags: r

I have data set for unemployment rate in Ireland. I want to do grouping, summarizing with data set. For example....

```
Period   Percent
2019Apr   5
2019Mar   4
2019Feb   4
2019Jan   3
2018Dec   2
2018NOV   4
```

I want output like this:

```
Period   Percent
2019       4.3  (Average of 2019Apr, 2019Mar....)
2018        3
2017        4
```

This is for a R programming language. I have tried subset and group by functions for grouping and summarizing.

I expect the output like this:

```
Period   Percent
2019       4.3  (Average of 2019Apr, 2019Mar....)
2018        3
2017        4
```

Comment: Could you please provide some data for us to work with? This seems like a `dplyr` kind of problem.

Comment: `library(dplyr); your_data %>% group_by(Period) %>% summarize(Percent = mean(Percent))`    https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/

Comment: You could probably use the gsub() function for parts like **2019Apr**. You would be able to get it like this **2019 Apr**. Oh well, thanks for the edit camille.

Comment: @JonSpring  thank for your help. But could you please tell me how to replace 2019Dec, 2019NOV in 2019

Comment: `library(tidyverse); your_data %>% group_by(Period = str_sub(Period, end=4)) %>% summarize(Percent = mean(Percent))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first remove the months from the year, since you don't need them. Then I'd group them and calculate the average. I've created the following example:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame("Period" = c("2019NOV", "2019DEC", "2019OCT", "2018DEC", "2018NOV"), "Percent" = c(1:5))

df1$Period <- sub("^(\\d{4}).*$", "\\1", df1$Period)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  group_by(Period) %>%
  summarize(Percent = mean(Percent))
```

Comment: @ Sven: Thank you for replay and formatting my questions. I tried your code but getting error: Column period can't be modified because it's a grouping variable.

Comment: I got desired output. Thank you